# Getting please set the query parameter changesNotSentForReview to true while releasing Android App from appcenter.ms

Tags: android, google-play-console, visual-studio-app-center, android-app-indexing, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

I am trying to build and distribute android app from appcenter.ms. Initially I got rejection after rolling out 3rd update and I tried to rebuild changes. But while distributing to store I got following issue.

> Edit could not be committed due to an error. Changes cannot be sent
> for review automatically. Please set the query parameter
> changesNotSentForReview to true. Once committed, the changes in this
> edit can be sent for review from the Google Play Console UI.

I don't want to make changes from Google Play Console UI and want to make changes from appcenter.ms only.
How to set that parameter in code.
Help will be really appreciable!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error with fastlane.
the problem was with an edit being reviewed that was not submitted.
In the play store dev console --> release overview --> change under review. there was an action to validate. it was the data security questionnaire.
once the form was submitted, I had no more problems with fastlane.

Comment: In our case was a previous release that was rejected that didn't allow a new build upload

Answer (score 1):

Had this same issue from AppCenter. There are some sites suggesting this is a setting in the API that is posting the app but AppCenter does not offer the setting.

The solution for me was to use 'Archive for Publishing' in Visual Studio for mac. If I then chose to 'sign and distribute' direct to Google play I would get the same issue as above.

By choosing 'Ad Hoc' distribution, then saving locally I would get a signed .aab file. This file can be manually uploaded to Google when editing a release.

I created a new track, manually uploaded, promoted it to testing then production without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Google Play Console UI is not that bad. You can still use the build generated by AppCenter that failed to upload.

In **AppCenter** go to ***Distribute > Releases > select your release > Download > Download aab***

Then in **Google play Console**, go to the same track you were using (no need to create a new one as suggested on another answer), click ***Create new release*** and apload the **.aab**.