# How to set changesNotSentForReview to true on AppCenter

Tags: android, google-play, appcenter

I'm getting the following error on AppCenter when I try to deploy it to Alpha Track on Google.

`Edit could not be committed due to an error. Changes cannot be sent for review automatically. Please set the query parameter changesNotSentForReview to true. Once committed, the changes in this edit can be sent for review from the Google Play Console UI.`

I couldn't find any documentation to solve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69085680/getting-please-set-the-query-parameter-changesnotsentforreview-to-true-while-rel

Comment: I'm assuming you did NOT find documentation?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a yaml pipeline you can add it like this:

```
        # Deploy to internal track
        - task: GooglePlayRelease@4
          inputs:
            authType: ''
            serviceAccountKey: ''
            applicationId: ''
            action: ''
            bundleFile: ''
            track: 'internal'
            releaseName: ''
            isDraftRelease: false # add these
            changesNotSentForReview: true # add these
          condition: ''
          displayName: Deploy release to Android Google Play internal track
```

Also check that you don't have a release already in draft or under review. And if it is your first submission maybe do it manually. Or if your last submission had issues that you haven't resolved, fix them first. These things change from time to time, but in my experience this error isn't always correct. I am getting it while I already have set the variable correctly.